# Como configurar proxy com usuario e senha no ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, proxy

Estou tentando configurar o proxy Ionic para efetuar downloads de projetos aqui na empresa mas alguma coisa está errada.

No npm o proxy está configurado e funciona bem (veja arquivo `.npmrc`):

```
proxy=http://DOMINIO%5CUSUARIO:00000%5FAAA@11.111.111.111:8080
```

Como podem ver o proxy possui usuário e senha e funciona perfeitamente, todas as dependências estão sendo baixadas.

Quando configuro o arquivo `config.json` do ionic conforme abaixo, me retorna um erro de conexão.

```
{
  "version": "5.4.5",
  "telemetry": true,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "tokens.telemetry": "40adsfasd-cff7-4dfsf-a760-5asdfasdbsdaf",
  "proxy": "http://DOMINIO%5CUSUARIO:00000%5FAAA@11.111.111.111:8080"  
}
```

Evidencia de erro:

```
C:\Temp\angular
> ionic start testeapp blank

Pick a framework!

Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply a value for the
--type option.

? Framework: Angular
√ Preparing directory .\testeapp - done!
- Downloading and extracting blank starter (45.40%)
Error: Encountered bad status code (407) for https://d2ql0qc7j8u4b2.cloudfront.net/angular-official-blank.tar.gz

This could mean the server is experiencing difficulties right now--please try again later.
at Request.req.on.res (C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\http.js:64:24)
at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Request._emitResponse
(C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:862:8)
at ClientRequest.req.once.res
(C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:412:10)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:15)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
/ Downloading and extracting blank starter (45.40%)
```

Alguém pode ajudar?